# Customizing Up/Back/Burger background in my ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to customize the background of my action bar items with a selector, to override what is shown when the button is pressed.
This was pretty easy with menu buttons (e.g., overflow icon), as you can style them with `actionBarItemBackground` .

Sadly this does not apply for the up/home/left indicator. I have unsuccessfully tried, in my styles.xml:

- `<item name="actionButtonStyle">`;
- `<item name="actionBarStyle">`;
- `<item name="toolbarStyle">`;

None of the nested attributes seem to act on the home icon background. I also searched over android.R.attr and gave a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style). Is there any way?

I would like to stay with the "up" indicator, without inflating a custom view. In that case, I would also have to inflate the title as well as custom views naturally appear at the end of the title. AND I would lose the burger-to-arrow animation, AND I would have to take care about margins and design guidelines (now managed by `AppCompat`), and some other bad thing on the way.

I thought about setting a `Logo`, but that would have some complications as well and I don't think I could change the background anyway.

I thought about `Toolbar` being a `Layout`, so I could put custom views in it from XML. If I'm not wrong they appear after the title, so neither this is a good idea.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please let me know if it works
add this to your your theme or if it doesn't take both remove the one with android  prefix

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
```

Example @drawable/selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="#ddffffff" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Hey @Panayiotis `selectableItemBackground` actually works. Now I'm gonna test it with some other widget - I fear it overrides the background of a lot of stuff, since it's declared in the main theme.

Comment: I'm not very happy with this solution, but it seems it's the only one out there. Thank you.