# Android toolbar icons style

Tags: android, styles, icons, toolbar

I'm working on an app which has two activites. The second activity has a back button which provide back navigation.

The problem I have is that the back navigation button takes the background from the toolbar no matter if the toolbar has the "style=" attribute or the "app:theme=".

Here is the toolbar with the "style=" attribute:

http://postimg.org/image/f57zaap4p/

http://postimg.org/image/3u5blxi9l/

An here is the toolbar with the "app:theme=" attribute:

htt.p://postimg.org/image/kkqxgo8d1/

htt.p://postimg.org/image/ofpq5i251/

(Please remove the point from "htt.p" from the last two links -  I can't post more than two links)

I want the icons to have a white background. I would appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can style the action overflow button in your styles.xml adding this line:

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">...</item>
```

You can set it as a `@drawable` or a `@color` resource. I suggest you to define a `selector` to manage, e.g, the background color as the icon is pressed.

As for the back arrow, this is, to me, quite an open question. You could take a look at my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680915/customizing-up-back-burger-background-in-my-actionbar) , where you can also find a `selector` sample.

Basically you can override the arrow/burger background with

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">...</item>
```

but (I fear) it acts as a background for a lot of widgets you might have. In facts, this also overrides `actionBarItemBackground`, so if you want to use both, the latter is enough.

Comment: The toggle is ok now but in the second activity the back button background is still red.

Comment: Make sure both activities inherit from the theme style you just edited. This can be done in your manifest file, with the `android:theme="@style/YourStyle"` for each `<activity>`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see no difference between the two. If the toolbar has no style, both activities load the toolbar the same way and have the same custom theme, & your arrow is actually working (i.e. is selectable) it should work.